# Hover does not change the font color

Tags: css

I have this code:

```css
.indexKomunikatyHover:hover>.indexKomunikatyHoverA>.indexKomunikatyData,
.indexKomunikatyHover:hover,
indexKomunikatyHoverLink.a:hover {
  background-color: #A92525;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.indexKomunikatyHover:hover a>.indexKomunikatyHoverA>.indexKomunikatyData,
indexKomunikatyHoverLink:hover a {
  color: white !important;
}

.indexKomunikatyHover>.indexKomunikatyHoverA>.indexKomunikatyData,
.indexKomunikatyHover a {
  color: #0B3375;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 padding0 padding2 indexKomunikatyHover">
  <a href="http://localhost/Messages" class=" indexKomunikatyHoverLink">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9  ">
      <div class="indexKomunikatyTytul">xxxxx zzzzz
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3  indexKomunikatyHoverA">
      <div class="indexKomunikatyData ">19 października 2019</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

If the cursor hovers over the lettering - the background color changes and the inscription "19 października 2019" changes to white. It works fine.

The background color for the string does not change: xxxxx zzzzz.

How to fix it?

Prwiev: https://jsfiddle.net/q3awthku/

Comment: You are not targeting the element with that class `indexKomunikatyTytul` anywhere in the CSS shown, so if that had its own background color set already from somewhere else in the CSS, that of course stays.

Comment: can you show me correct code?

Comment: It seems to be working in the snippet (the string "xxxxx zzzzz" is included in the area where the background color changes). Maybe there's another rule not shown here that interacts? Or do you experiment this on a specific browser (firefox here)? Or else you should be more precise about your problem

Comment: No, not with the current given example. The whole container gets a red-ish background, and that shows behind the xxxxx zzzzz text as well … so it is not even clear what you actually want.

Comment: I need to change the background to red and the color of the text to white. At the moment, the background and the color of the "19 października" lettering change correctly. The text color "xxxxx zzzzz" does not change ant this is my problem

Comment: First of all, you are not targetting your classes properly. You forgot to add a "." before some of your classnames in your css. Second, If you want to target .indexKomunikatyHoverLink as a link, it's a.indexKomunikatyHoverLink:hover, not indexKomunikatyHoverLink:hover a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My tip would be not to use such long selectors - you are making maintainability a lot harder and the efficiency of the selectors a lot lower as well as making it harder to override things which is probably why you are using `!important` like that

```css
.indexKomunikatyHover a { /* original colour of anchors */
  color: #0B3375;
}

.indexKomunikatyHover:hover {  /* just change background on main div */
  background-color: #A92525;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.indexKomunikatyHover:hover a { /* just change the colour on anchors when main div is hovered */
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 padding0 padding2 indexKomunikatyHover">
  <a href="http://localhost/Messages" class=" indexKomunikatyHoverLink">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9  ">
      <div class="indexKomunikatyTytul">xxxxx zzzzz
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3  indexKomunikatyHoverA">
      <div class="indexKomunikatyData ">19 października 2019</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```